# in vs2019 lnk2019, lnk1120 errors occurred. I used CoolProp.dll. A build error occurs due to an unresolved external symbol referenced in a function

Tags: c++

I am developing a project that creates a dynamic dll.

CoolPropLib.h was added to the additional include directory.

coolprop.lib was added to linker dependencies.

An error message appears in coolprop's PropsSI: "Unresolved external symbol referenced in function."
Are there any lib, dll, h files referenced in coolprop?

Please solve this problem
thank you

**cool.cpp**

```
double afunction()
{
   CoolProp Cool;
   double result = Cool.Cp_Of_Water(1);
   return result;

}
```

**cool.h**

```
#include <CoolPropLib.h>
typedef struct CoolProp
{
//# ====== Thermo-Material Properties function
    double Cp_Of_Water(double temp)
    {
        temp = min(temp, 373.15);
        return PropsSI("C", "T", temp, "P", P, "water");
    }
}
```

**error message**

> LNK2019 : "double __cdecl PropsSI(char const *,char const *,double,char const *,double,char const *)" (?PropsSI@@YANPEBD0N0N0@Z)"public: double __cdecl CoolProp::Cp_Of_Water(double)" (?Cp_Of_Water@CoolProp@@QEAANN@Z)

Comment: Check with `dumpbin` what symbols your library exports.

Comment: When I ran dumpbin, it showed that propssi exists as 30 1D 00190A70 PropsSI.

Comment: Is coolproplib built in C? And does the header contain the necessary `extern "C" ` markers to disable name mangling?

Comment: It became normal when creating an MFC program with the corresponding DLL.
I want to use coolProp.dll from C++ .dll on C# server.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are you saying that I should check extern "C" when I CMAKE Coolprop.dll again?

Comment: You should check the *header file* (coolproplib.h) to see if it contains the necessary `extern "C"` annotations.

Comment: I am a beginner developer.
Below is a part of the coolproplib.h file.
I can't find any external references.